# escape comma in concatenation in php

Tags: javascript, php

```
$html .='
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#owl-caro").owlCarousel({
        rewindNav: false,
        navigationText: [\''.'<i classs="navigator fa fa-caret-left"></i>\''.',\'<i class="navigator fa fa-caret-right"></i>\''.']

    });

</script>';
```

almost there, but my left caret is missing, I suspect it was caused by the comma.

the option is like this navigationText: ["prev","next"] in js

Comment: Don't suspect a.k.a. guess, but look at the rendered html instead

Comment: @PeeHaa It seem correct but it doesn't.. so I still suspect the comma caused the error.

Comment: Do you know about [Heredoc string quoting syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the motivation behind concatenating these strings at all -- why not `navigationText: [\'<i class="..."></i>\', ...` -- in other words just remove all the `'.'` occurrences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a spelling mistake for "class"

```
navigationText: ['<i classs - (it should be class)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 s in i classs. Change it to `<i class=`